# Why Angularjs Routing Concept does not work in Notepad++?

Tags: angularjs, notepad++

In Notepad++ tools Angular Routing does not working.
I Tried to Link all angular links

Scotch Tutorials

Above Tutorial Link Working in Online,But does not working in Notepad++.

Comment: Please provide some code, and a further explanation of the problem so we can get an idea of what you're doing.

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg/

Comment: This is the Link using download And save the desktop then After open in Notepad++ and the output does not working

Answer (score 1):

From the comments you've provided it's because you've used;

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">
```

You need to specify the angular App instead like so;

```
<body ng-app="scotchApp">
```

This makes sure your index page uses the module App, rather than explicitly the controller.

Hope it helps!

Comment: When did i use ng-controller

Comment: Hi Tom your Method does not working please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you understand the Problem

Comment: Line 18 of the link you provided in markup. Are you running the scripts correctly on the HTML page, reference them at the bottom of the page, and don't forget to include angular.js

Comment: Just U can Share the Screenshot